# Redirecting stderr/stdout with Notebook/IPython/IDLE: io.UnsupportedOperation: 'fileno'

Tags: python, windows, jupyter

I am doing a Python wrapper of a C library to control some hardware and the detailed error messages are sent to stderr -- via fprintf I guess.

Using this code (redirection of `sys.stderr` fileno) https://gist.github.com/arenaudineau/c79b1a81dc1c536aa4f48dacb091490b to wrap a call:

From the python interpreter: everything OK
Inside a Jupyter Notebook or IDLE: exception `io.UnsupportedOperation: 'fileno'`

I understand that they are overwriting `sys.stderr` but my question then is how can I get it to work within a Notebook? (that I need to use, I do not really care about IDLE actually)

I catched the exception and instead use `sys.__stderr__` fileno. Now no more exception but it just does not fill the buffer so this one must not be the right one either.

NB: I am working on Windows with Python 32-bits version (because of the hardware... pyvisa drivers and all) and do not need something portable.

Comment: Update: I am using the Visual Studio Code jupyter notebook extension. By using it in my browser, it works....